# ¿Cómo hago un arreglo de meses en Java para calcular impuestos anuales?

Tags: java

Necesito hacer un arreglo de meses para que al final del año pueda sumar el impuesto de todos los meses y obtener la renta anual

Lo que tengo es lo siguiente:

```
String[] mes={"enero", "febrero", "marzo", "abril", "mayo", "junio", "julio", "agosto", "setiembre", "octubre", "noviembre", "diciembre"};

System.out.println("Ingrese los ingresos brutos mensuales del mes"+mes[]+"de la persona: ");
int ingresosBrutosMensuales = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución es sencilla  y **puedes optar por varias opciones dependiendo si quieres rescatar , en un momento dado, los ingresos mensuales o solo cálcular el totalAnual después de pedir los ingresos mensuales**.

**Solución sencilla:**

1. Debes declarar una variable int (totalIngresosAño por ejemplo) para guardar el total del año. Además, debes inicializarla a 0.
2. Hacer un recorrido con un for sobre cada uno de los meses del arreglo mes[], solicitar el ingreso de ese mes y actualizar la variable totalIngresosAño
3. Finalmente mostrar el total.

Algo así:

```
String[] mes = {"enero", "febrero", "marzo", "abril", "mayo", "junio", "julio", "agosto", "setiembre", "octubre", "noviembre", "diciembre"};
        int ingresoBrutoAnual = 0;
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(System.in);

        for (int i=0;i<mes.length;i++) {
            System.out.println("Ingrese los ingresos brutos mensuales del mes " + mes[i] + " de la persona: ");
            int ingresosBrutosMensuales = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
            ingresoBrutoAnual = ingresoBrutoAnual + ingresosBrutosMensuales;
        }

        System.out.println("Los ingresos brutos del años son: " + ingresoBrutoAnual);
```

**Solución más compleja:**

La solución más compleja, pero que presenta todas las ventajas de la programación OO (entre ellas reutilización y encapsulación), pasa por hacer una clase llamada Persona que permita gestionar y almacenar (en una instancia) toda la información relativa a sus ingresos, eso te lo dejo como trabajo extra. Pero, algunas pistas:

1. Crear una variable int[] ingresosBrutosPorMes.
2. Crear el constructor para inicializar dicha variable.
3. Crear el método para pedir al usuario los ingresos mensuales y rellenar la variable ingresosBrutosPorMes.
4. Crear los métodos necesarios para obtener la suma de los ingresosBrutosPorMes, es decir el totalIngresos Anual.

Comment: David! Está explicación está súper completa, la estoy utilizando como guía para hacer mi algoritmo. De hecho estoy haciendo lo que me dejaste de tarea porque mi ejercicio necesita calcular la renta anual de una persona que de acuerdo a su salario tiene diferentes impuestos, entonces voy a intentarlo con tu guía

Comment: Me alegro que se sea de utilidad. Si te sirve la ayuda no dudes en puntuar la respuesta. Gracias.

Comment: David, tengo una duda, cuando pongo esto el sistema no me lo corre porque dice que no es posible convertir de double a int, pero yo no tengo ningún double acá, sabes por qué es? "
            if (rentaNeta > 3628000) {
                rentaNetaMensual = rentaNeta * 0.10;
                System.out.println("La renta neta con los impuestos incluidos de  " + mes[i] + "es de : " + rentaNeta);"

Comment: Cuando haces rentaNetaMensual = rentaNeta * 0.10; la parte derecha de la expresion se convierte en un double (estás multiplicando por 0.10). Entonces, como estas intentando asignar un double (la parte derecha del = ) a un entero, te lanza un error ya que ha truncamiento de datos. Lo mejor es que redefinas tus variables para trabajar siempre con valores decimales, es decir double.

Comment: Ahhh ya comprendo, no sabía que esos decimales me afectaban en el int.  Al final de mi algoritmo cuando quiero sumar todas las partes, no me lo reconoce, me dice: "array required but double found" Y así es como lo puse yo: "  double rentaAnual = rentaNetaMensual[i];
                            System.out.println("La renta anual de la persona es de: " + rentaAnual);"

Comment: Bueno, el mismo mensaje te lo dice. En la linea donde tienes el error estás tratando un double como si fuera un array. Imagina que declaro un double tal que así myDouble = 0.0; y luego lo trato de esta manera myDouble[i] = 1.0. A la parte izquierda de la expresion se espera un array pero no lo es.